# for(x in X) fails, but writing it out in full succeeds

Tags: javascript, iterator

This is vexing. As can be seen from the below code annotation, the clean way fails yet the messy way succeeds.

But the messy way is just surely doing what the clean way does behind the scenes.

But obviously something must be different!

What's going on?

```
function onSuccess( access ) 
{
    log("requestMIDIAccess -- granted!");

    midiAccess = access; // for persistence over closure

    var inputs = midiAccess.inputs;
    var gotOne = false;

    if (inputs.length === 0)
        log( "No MIDI inputs detected. Maybe reload Chrome THEN connect?" );
    else {   

//      var inputs = midiAccess.inputs.values();      // A WORKS
//      for ( var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) 

        for ( input in midiAccess.inputs.values() )   // B FAILS
        {
            input.value.onmidimessage = myMIDIMessagehandler;
            gotOne = true;
        }
        if( ! gotOne ) log( "Need at least one MIDI input" );

    }
```

EDIT: using `for..of` and `var input` now, but still fails.

EDIT: I am using https://github.com/cwilso/WebMIDIAPIShim --  that is where the `access` object is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change `input.value.onmidimessage` to `input.onmidimessage`, and it works!

```
    for ( var input of midiAccess.inputs.values() ) 
    {
        log( "Input: " + input );
        input.onmidimessage = myMIDIMessagehandler;
        gotOne = true;
    }
    if( ! gotOne ) log( "Need at least one MIDI input" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The **for..in** statement iterates over the **enumerable properties** of an object, in arbitrary order. Probably not what you want

It looks like  midiAccess.inputs.values(); is an ES6 iterator? if that is the case, you may be able to use

```
for (var input of midiAccess.inputs.values())
```

Comment: If you're using ES6, use `let` rather than `var`.

Comment: `of` is better, I've changed to it and edited the question. But it doesn't solve the problem!  `let` would be incorrect I think, as `input` gets modified.

Comment: Gah, I've been learning Swift which uses `var` and `let`. Needless to say they mean entirely different things from JS's `var` and `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `for (var input in midiAccess.inputs.values() )`.

You have to delcare input.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the question. But still the problem persists.